# I am having an issue below is the SQL query written in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

With the given query I am getting multiple vehicle data that occur between two dates ex. from 1-7-2022 to 31-08-2022.
With clarity I wanted to search a list of vehicles that test is due with this given date, I am getting that data with the below query but I am not able to exclude the vehicle that is already tested. for ex: there is a vehicle 'ABC' that is tested  5 times on the above-given date now I wanted to check if the vehicle testing is due in between these time periods. If due then show me in the list else remove the vehicle no from the list So please suggest any logic or query for that.

```
<?php
$jobcards = Jobcard::with('job_test_types')
                ->whereIn('filled_forms.updated_at',[$from ,$to])
                ->whereNotIn("jobcards.status", ["Unbilled", "FillingRemain", "Cancelled"])
                ->join("filled_forms", "filled_forms.job_no", "=", "jobcards.job_no")
                ->join('vehicles', 'jobcards.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')
                ->join("vehicle_type", "vehicle_type.id", "=", "vehicles.vehicle_type")
                ->join('customers', 'jobcards.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
                ->select('jobcards.*', 'vehicles.reg_no', 'customers.customer_name', 'vehicle_type.vehicle_type as vehicle_type', 
                         'customers.mobile as cust_mobile', "filled_forms.updated_at as test_date", "filled_forms.form_id as form_id")
                ->where('jobcards.workshop_id', $w_id)->get();
    
$final_jobcards = [];

foreach ($jobcards as $key => $value) {

$test_details = TestType::where("form_id", "=", $value->form_id)
                ->join("test_expiries", "test_expiries.test_type_id", "=", "test_types.id")
                ->select("test_expiries.months as test_exp_month")
                ->first();
                //return $test_details;

if ($test_details) {
    $jobcards[$key]->expiry_date = date_format(Carbon::parse($jobcards[$key]->test_date)->addMonths($test_details->test_exp_month), 'd-m-Y');
    $temp = date_format(Carbon::parse($jobcards[$key]->test_date)->addMonths($test_details->test_exp_month), 'Y-m-d');
    $last_date = date_format(Carbon::parse($jobcards[$key]->test_date),'Y-m-d');
} else {
    $jobcards[$key]->expiry_date = date_format(Carbon::parse($jobcards[$key]->test_date)->addMonths(12), 'd-m-Y');
    $temp = date_format(Carbon::parse($jobcards[$key]->test_date)->addMonths(12), 'Y-m-d');
}

$jobcards[$key]->test_date = date_format(Carbon::parse($jobcards[$key]->test_date), 'd-m-Y');

$currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($temp));
$startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from));
$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($to));

if ($currentDate >= $startDate && $currentDate <= $endDate) {
    $final_jobcards[] = $jobcards[$key];
}
```

Comment: Just a thought ...  "whereIn('filled_forms.updated_at',[$from ,$to])" , should this be "whereBetween" ?

Comment: i'm cant read this monster , but there is functions you can search without using join in Laravel Like `whereRalation` or `whereHas`, read in Laravel document: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#inline-relationship-existence-queries,              ,,,,,,,              https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence